# An array that calculates the amount of times a certain number is entered - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am teaching myself java and have picked up a book with some exercises.  One of these exercises requires me to build a console application that reads numbers from the keyboard into an array of type int[].  There can be 50 or fewer entries in the array.

So let's say someone enters 2,3,4,2,2,3

The output should be 2 columns with the number on the left, and the number of times on the right (as below for the above numbers)

2  3
3  2
4  1

I am not sure the best way to go about this as I am very new to java.

What I have so far is:

EDIT:  With a bit of work from the advice from some people here, this is what I now have.

```
package arrayassignment;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Entry {

    private Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);  
    private int[] count = new int[51];
    private  int input = scn.nextInt();

    private void setInput(int input){
        this.input = input;
    }
    private int getInput(){
        return input;
    }         

    public void numberEntry(){
    System.out.println("Please enter numbers between 0 and 50:");
    for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
    if (input == x)
        count[x]++;
    }
  }
```

I plan on calling these methods from the main method class rather than doing everything from the main method as according to the book, this is the best OO approach.

Your input would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your `getMyScanner` method looks odd. Conventionally, `get` methods return something. The assignment within the function also seems meaningless. It's equal to `this.myScanner = this.myScanner`.

Comment: Are they only ever single digit numbers?

Comment: Instead of doing it as a class, maybe you should do it as a method()

Comment: The main is in a different class.

Comment: Is your input all in 1 string with commas (,) or they are keyed in seperately?

Comment: as mentioned by pakkudon your get method is not worth . you should write return myScanner; now coming back to your problem you can use hashmap where you will insert number as key and its count as value. before putting value in map check if number is already put in , if yes then increment that count if not then put number as key and 1 as count

Comment: @user3437460 from what I believe each int will be separated by a space so just a long string like 4 5 6 7 4 5 3

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
int input;
int[] count = new int[10];
input = scn.nextInt();

for (int x=0; x<10; x++)
    if (input == x)
        count[x]++;
```

There are several ways to implement this. The above code will check what number the user has keyed in and add 1 accordingly to its respective counter records. This may not be the most effective way, but this is one possible ways you can use.

(As your question did not specify whether the inputs are in string with commas or individual integers, I am **assuming** your inputs are individual integers.)

Comment: The numbers will be entered as space separated strings like 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 4 5 6 7

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; 1 < digits.length; i++);
```

The semicolon is going to pose a problem in your for loop. 
Also why is digits set at 51 if the array is supposed to be set at 50 elements?

The simplest of ways to search for a specific element in your array will probably be with a sequential search algorithm. You're probably going to want to do is create a method that accepts the int array and the value as an argument, searches through each element in the array and returns an int value for the number of times the value was found.

```
 public static int sequentialSearch(int[] digits, int value){
  int counter = 0;
  for(int index = 0; index< digits.length; index++){
   if(digits[index]  == value){
      counter++;
     }
   }
   return counter;
 }
```

Then in your main method of your class add this line to see the following example work:

```
 int[] digits = {1,3,5,6,4,3,3,3,10};
 System.out.println(sequentialSearch(digits, 3));
```

In the example above the console will out put 4 as the value 3 was found four times in the digits array.

Comment: I am doing it to 51 to allow the use of the number 50.  The question states numbers up to 50 so it is a little vague, seeing as though arrays start at 0.

Comment: If the directions are calling for 50 elements the last element in the array will be 49. The nth array elements start at 0 and end at n-1.